# Using provider in an api call

Tags: flutter

I have a method that that makes an api call. Within the method I want to save data from the call to firestore. My firestore database is using Provider for injection.

```
    Future<String> getData(String query) async {
    print('getdata called');
    List<Suburb> suburbs = await model.getSuburbs('au', query);

    if (suburbs.length == 1) {
      final suburb= suburbs[0];
      final database = Provider.of<Database>(context);   // My firestore database. When I remove these lines, I get the expected return. 
      await database.setSuburb(suburb);
     return suburb.name;

    } else...{return}

Removing the firestore write, gives me the expected return. But when I try to save the data, I don't get anything returned. The write never happens either.  So I presume the problem is there or maybe I'm doing something incorrect in the method. I don't get any error logs either...

here is the firestore method:


    setSuburb(Suburb suburb)async{
        final path = '/voters/$uid/';
        final documentReference = Firestore.instance.document(path);
         await documentReference.setData({"location.suburb":suburb}, merge: true);
    }

EDIT:
The method gets called by a listener on a `textfield`. This future is the future for the FutureBuilder.


    void inputListener() {
        if (_controller.text.length == 4) {
          query = _controller.text;
          setState(() {
            future = getData(query);
            _controller.clear();
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          });
        }
      }
EDIT
FutureBuilder(
                    future: future,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return (Text(snapshot.data));
                      }
                      return Text('no postcode');
                    }),
```

Comment: if I understand you right, you mean  "return suburb.name;" is returning null unless you remove this line  "final database = Provider.of<Database>(context);" ?? And can you provide more code like how are you calling this method

Comment: yes, that's correct. The method is a future that's used in a FutureBuilder. Code updated...

Comment: can you also provide the FutureBuilder, because I am suspecting that you are not checking the connectionState maybe?

Comment: updated code   ...

Comment: in the FutureBuilder just check two conditions:
 if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting),

and  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)

and in this second case you then check if(snapshot.hasData), try it and tell the result